# Aggregation over Partition in pandas

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am looking for the best way to aggregate values based on a particular partition , an equivalent of

```sql
SUM(TotalCost) OVER(PARTITION BY ShopName) Earnings  ( SQL server)
```

I am able to do this by the following steps in Pandas, but I'm looking for a native approach.

```py
TempDF = DF.groupby(by=['ShopName'])['TotalCost'].sum()
 
TempDF = TempDF.reset_index() 
      
NewDF = pd.merge(DF , TempDF, how='inner', on='ShopName')
```

Answer (score 57):

You can use pandas transform() method for within group aggregations like "OVER(partition by ...)" in SQL:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#create dataframe with sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],'value':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})

#calculate AVG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY group)
df['mean_value'] = df.groupby('group').value.transform(np.mean)

df:
group   value   mean_value
A       1       2
A       2       2
A       3       2
B       4       5
B       5       5
B       6       5
```

Answer (score 3):

Another very fast option is to map the aggregation from `groupby` back to the original frame.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],'value':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})

means = df.groupby('group')['value'].mean()
df['mean_value'] = df['group'].map(means)
```

---

In some use cases, this is the fastest choice. Especially if there are many groups and the function passed to `groupby` is not optimized. An example is to find the mode of each group; `groupby.transform` is over twice as slow.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': pd.Index(range(1000)).repeat(1000), 
                   'value': np.random.default_rng().choice(10, size=1000000)})

%timeit df['group'].map(df.groupby('group')['value'].agg(pd.Series.mode))
# 278 ms ± 6.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df.groupby('group')['value'].transform(pd.Series.mode)
# 621 ms ± 7.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```