# Execute SQL query in python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandasql

How can we execute sql in python pandas :

SQL :

```
select 
a.*, 
b.vol1 / sum(vol1) over (
  partition by a.sale, a.d_id, 
  a.month, a.p_id
) vol_r, 
a.vol2* b.vol1/ sum(b.vol1) over (
  partition by a.sale, a.d_id, 
  a.month, a.p_id
) vol_t
from 
sales1 a 
left join sales2 b on a.sale = b.sale
and a.d_id = b.d_id 
and a.month = b.month
and a.p_id = b.p_id
```

I know one way is pandasql but getting error as sql involves partition by.

Comment: For the `partition by` part, I'd refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905335/aggregation-over-partition-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @DanielLenz This doesn't work as I have multiplication which won't happen in transform.