# python pandas column with averages

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I have a dataframe with in column "A" locations and in column "B" values. Locations occure multiple times in this DataFrame, now i'd like to add a third column in which i store the average value of column "B" that have the same location value in column "A".

-I know the .mean() can be used to get an average

-I know how to filter with .loc()

I could make a list of all unique values in column A, and compute the average for all of them by making a for loop. Hover, this seems combersome to me. Any idea how this can be done more efficiently?

Comment: check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905335/aggregation-over-partition-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you need is GroupBy. Take a look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html)

Given

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                   'B': [np.nan, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'C': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2]}, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

You can use

```
df.groupby('A').mean()
```

to group the values based on the common values in column "A" and find the mean.

Output:

```
     B         C
A
1  3.0  1.333333
2  4.0  1.500000
```

Answer (score 1):

> I could make a list of all unique values in column A, and compute the
> average for all of them by making a for loop.

This can be done using [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) consider following simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["X","Y","Y","X","X"],"B":[1,3,7,10,20]})
means = df.groupby('A').agg('mean')
print(means)
```

gives output

```
           B
A
X  10.333333
Y   5.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': [32, 61, 40, 45]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df2 = df.groupby(['A']).mean()
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I'm not sure if you are trying to simply calculate the averages for each group, or if you are wanting to maintain the [long format](https://www.statology.org/long-vs-wide-data/) of your data. I'll break down a solution for each option.

The data I'll use below can be generated by running the following...

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['group1 ', 2],
                   ['group2 ', 4],
                   ['group1 ', 5],
                   ['group2 ', 2],
                   ['group1 ', 2],
                   ['group2 ', 0]], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

#### Option 1 - Calculate Group Averages

This one is super simple. It uses the `.groupby` method, which is the bread and butter of crunching data calculations.

```py
df.groupby('A').B.mean()
```

**Output:**

```
A
group1     3.0
group2     2.0
```

If you wish for this to return a dataframe instead of a series, you can add `.to_frame()` to the end of the above line.

#### Option 2 - Calculate Group Averages and Maintain Long Format

By long format, I mean you want your data to be structured the same as it is currently, but with a third column (we'll call it `C`) containing a mean that is connected to the `A` column. ie...

| A | B | C (average) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| group1 | 2 | 3 |
| group2 | 4 | 2 |
| group1 | 5 | 3 |
| group2 | 2 | 2 |
| group1 | 2 | 3 |
| group2 | 0 | 2 |

Where the averages for each group are...

```
group1 = (2+5+2)/3 = 3
group2 = (4+2+0)/3 = 2
```

The most efficient solution, would be to use `.transform`, which behaves like an sql window function, but I think this method can be a little confusing when you're new to pandas.

```
import numpy as np
df.assign(C=df.groupby('A').B.transform(np.mean))
```

A less efficient, but more beginner friendly option would be to store the averages in a dictionary and then map each row to the group average.

> I find myself using this option a lot for modeling projects, when I want to impute a historical average rather than the average of my sampled data.

To accomplish this, you can...

1. Create a dictionary containing the grouped averages
2. For every row in the dataframe, pass the group name into the dictionary

```py
# Create the group averages
group_averages = df.groupby('A').B.mean().to_dict()
# For every row, pass the group name into the dictionary
new_column = df.A.map(group_averages)
# Add the new column to the dataframe
df = df.assign(C=new_column)
```

You can also, optionally, do all of this in a single line

```py
df = df.assign(C=df.A.map(df.groupby('A').B.mean().to_dict()))
```