# Pandas/python min value in a sequence/group, reset by column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Stuck coming from SQL world, trying to use `pandas` and resist the urge to go back to the `database` and write this where I am more comfortable.

For my purposes, just assume there are four columns
[FIRST_NAME][LAST_NAME][CAR_ID][DATE]

I want to add a column, let’s call it [MIN_DATE]

```
BOB ONE 1234 1/1/2020
BOB ONE 1234 2/1/2020
BOB ONE 2345 3/1/2020
BOB ONE 2345 4/1/2020
BOB ONE 1234 1/1/2023
BOB ONE 1234 2/1/2023
BOB TWO 1234 1/1/2022
BOB TWO 1234 2/1/2022
BOB TWO 2345 3/1/2022
BOB TWO 2345 4/1/2022
BOB TWO 1234 3/1/2023
BOB TWO 1234 4/1/2023
```

I want to add a column with the first value for DATE reset on the sorted list whenever the car_id changes. I don’t know enough about `pandas` to know if there is a function that can do this. Or, if I should just be trying to do it in python.

```
BOB ONE 1234 1/1/2020 1/1/2020
BOB ONE 1234 2/1/2020 1/1/2020
BOB ONE 2345 3/1/2020 3/1/2020
BOB ONE 2345 4/1/2020 3/1/2020
BOB ONE 1234 1/1/2023 1/1/2023
BOB ONE 1234 2/1/2023 1/1/2023
BOB TWO 1234 1/1/2022 1/1/2022
BOB TWO 1234 2/1/2022 1/1/2022
BOB TWO 2345 3/1/2022 3/1/2022
BOB TWO 2345 4/1/2022 3/1/2022
BOB TWO 1234 3/1/2023 3/1/2023
BOB TWO 1234 4/1/2023 3/1/2023
```

I can't simply group by name and ID and get the min, because that would give me the top value for the later record.

```
BOB ONE 1234 1/1/2020 1/1/2020 <<
BOB ONE 1234 2/1/2020 1/1/2020
BOB ONE 2345 3/1/2020 3/1/2020
BOB ONE 2345 4/1/2020 3/1/2020
BOB ONE 1234 1/1/2023 1/1/2023 << group by would give 1/1/2020 but i  need 1/1/2023
BOB ONE 1234 2/1/2023 1/1/2023 <<
```

Struggling to figure out how to approach this with `pandas`. Ideally want a function that I can just say Minimum date over name, car ID, reset context on change in name and car ID based on sort – which is something I've seen in other data tools, just can't figure out if there's anything like this in pandas.

addressing comment from sundace:
simple group by does not work in your example, since the sequence matters and I need to reset on a change in value in the sequence.

df['min_value'] = df.groupby('group').value.transform(np.min)

extending your example you will see the problem is not quite the same so your solution does not work for this

```
A 1 1
A 2 1
A 3 1
B 4 4
B 5 4
B 5 4
A 6 1 <order of the list matters, this should reflect 4 not 1
A 7 1
A 8 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

- First turn your `DATE` strings into datetime using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).
- For `CAR_ID` we want to put consecutive values into separate groups. Check for inequality ([`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html)) with the column's shift ([`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)). A new group starts where `True`, so we can apply [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to get the groups.
- Now add the result to the other groups inside [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), select `DATE` and apply [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `min`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# turn date strings into datetime 
# (N.B. your date format is ambiguous! Adjust if it is `%m/%d/%Y`!)

df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

# consecutive values to groups
car_g = df['CAR_ID'].ne(df['CAR_ID'].shift()).cumsum()

# add `car_g` inside groupby, get `min` transformed and assign
df['MIN_DATE'] = df.groupby(['FIRST_NAME','LAST_NAME',car_g])['DATE'].transform('min')

df

   FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME  CAR_ID       DATE   MIN_DATE
0         BOB       ONE    1234 2020-01-01 2020-01-01
1         BOB       ONE    1234 2020-01-02 2020-01-01
2         BOB       ONE    2345 2020-01-03 2020-01-03
3         BOB       ONE    2345 2020-01-04 2020-01-03
4         BOB       ONE    1234 2023-01-01 2023-01-01
5         BOB       ONE    1234 2023-01-02 2023-01-01
6         BOB       TWO    1234 2022-01-01 2022-01-01
7         BOB       TWO    1234 2022-01-02 2022-01-01
8         BOB       TWO    2345 2022-01-03 2022-01-03
9         BOB       TWO    2345 2022-01-04 2022-01-03
10        BOB       TWO    1234 2023-01-03 2023-01-03
11        BOB       TWO    1234 2023-01-04 2023-01-03
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick. Just in case of sequential car_id I added a hash column that I used your shift and group solution for. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your problem is actually very straight forward and it has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905335/aggregation-over-partition-in-pandas).

you want to aggregate over a group like in sql :

```
min(value) over (partition by group)
```

in pandas :

```
#calculate min(value) OVER (PARTITION BY group)
df['min_value'] = df.groupby('group').value.transform(np.min)
```

the result will be the minium value for each group you chose :

```
df:
group   value   min_value
A       1       1
A       2       1
A       3       1
B       4       4
B       5       4
B       6       4
```

dont forget about importing numpy as np .

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though.
your example is not equivalent to my problem. extending your example you will see why it does not work for my case

A 1 1
A 2 1
A 3 1
B 4 4
B 5 4
B 5 4
A 6 1 <order of the list matters, this should reflect 4 not 1
A 7 1
A 8 1

Comment: it does answer your question , you just want to group by two columns , which are the name of the person and the date .
so you will just do : groupby(['group1','group2'])

Comment: It does not. Group by two columns name and date would give me the unique row.

Comment: Ok i get what you are trying to do , but you have to specify the logic behind the wanted value , why do you want that specific value to be the intended result , isit because its a new year ? how do i decide that a change has occured .